# Why is the Android debugger of the Xamarin project inaccessible?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

My question is how to debug and fix a Xamarin solution with an Android project that fails to run any Android emulator/debugger? I have not modified any code since the project was initialized. My code is the same after creating a project. For this reason I expect a configuration setting is to blame, but I need some help to figure out what exactly is preventing the Android debugger from running.

Background: I have tried to run several Android projects from several Xamarin solutions. I have two Windows 10 computers. The one I'm using now is the Pro edition. I do not use a VHD. The processor is 64 bit. I have 8GB of RAM, mostly free. The CPU supports `SSSE3` [instructions](http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/670/AMD_Turion_64_Mobile_technology_ML-40_vs_Intel_Core_i5_Mobile_i5-4210U.html) as the processor is an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz. *Almost* every other project fails to fully launch the debugger. Windows phone projects will start the debugger, but nothing shows up after `Windows Phone OS is starting...` shows on the emulator's screen. Windows Phone projects using Xamarin Forms (shared not portable) work fine for debugging as shown in the image below:

[image]

I do consistently get the following warning when trying to debug an Android project:

```
An unexpected error occurred trying to initialize Android Designer. Please verify the Android SDK path and the  Java Development Kit path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu. Please see the logs for more details.          0
```

I don't see anything out of the ordinary in the configuration settings. The SDK uses an x86 version, but I have read nothing in the [requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx#Checklist) that states that anything different is required. Also, there is SLAP, DEP, and hardware virtualization.

[image: In the Xamarin Menu of Visual Studio 2015's Tool Options the window shows file paths to the JDK, SDK, and Android NDK.]

Comment: Do you have any other error information? Based on the error you've posted, you've already correctly set the Java Development Kit Location.

Comment: Honestly this sounds normal. Killing MSBuild.exe from Task menu..Killing Adb.exe from task menu. Cleaning and rebuilding. Restarting the IDE and rebooting are normal requirements for Xamarin Development and debuging. At least they have been for me. Theres so many moving parts and so many layers between the C# and the phone that it can seem pretty unstable at times.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, I get the following warning for my Xamarin portable forms: `
The "CreateAdditionalLibraryResourceCache" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. `

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, 'The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.InternalGetDirectoryName(String path)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfChanged(String source, String destination)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.CreateAdditionalLibraryResourceCache.Execute()'

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, '   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() XamarinTestPortableForms.Droid''

Comment: @David stoping the services, cleaning, and rebuilding did not help.

Comment: Well the first one Looks like your using a fairly deep location withen your file system for your project. Try moving the solution Folder out to C:

Comment: @David, your suggestion was a direct hit! Moving the solution three directories removed from C:\ was sufficient in fact to fix the problem. I would like to make your comment as an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Xamarin has a number of Nuances you have to be familiar with for things to work well. One of those is the 260 character limit of the Simulator to access the adb file. If the total length of the path includung file name exceeds the 260 limit you get this error. Easiest answer is to move your Solution up to the root of you C:. Be carefully sticking it on a Mapped drive to get around this issue as I've heard this can cause other issues.